# Did the Prophet wrestle with his friends in the masjid (as practice)?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, source-identification

Salam,

A while back I heard that the Prophet used to wrestle in the mosque with his friends when they would see each other but not like wwe or actual punching but more like grappling and throwing to the floor.

***My question is where can I find this Hadith if it exists?***

Answer (score 1):

[Islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/326929) says:

> ولا نعلم دليلا على أن هذه المصارعة أو غيرها تمت في مسجد رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم
>
> We do not know of any evidence that this wrestling (i.e. with [Rukanah](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4078))  or any other occurred in the masjid of the Messenger of Allah ﷺ

Comment: Oh right ok jazakallah khair.